# Should there be a link to fill in user info in the About Me box?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, profile-page, user-information

By default, the About Me box is just a gray rectangle with nothing inside. I've been using Stack Overflow for 6 months and always assumed it was an ad that was blocked by AdBlock. Today I learned that it is, in fact, the "About Me" box.

In order to incite users to fill in this information (or simply to let them know what this box is used for), shouldn't there be some link text in the box?

For example, if the About Me info box is left empty, then add add some discreet link such as:

> [Fill your "About Me" information now](http://www.example.com/)

The link should be in a small font and discreet color so that's it's not in your face, but the presence of some explanatory text would be useful for those wondering what this box is all about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be, we can do something like this. Of course, the text should appear only if the box is completely gray (in other words if the About Me section is not filled in).

*Option #1:* Added this option based on the comment from @Laurent.

[image: Mock up 1]

*Option #2 :*  I hope users will be curious enough to click on the `What's this?` link which can act the same way as `edit` link.

[image: Mock up 2]

Comment: I'd go for something in the bottom right corner in small fonts. That way, if someone wants to know what's the box for, they can find out. And if they don't care, they won't have a big message reminding them every day.

Comment: @Laurent - that's what designers are for isn't it? The idea here is sound.

Comment: @Laurent: There you go. Added the second mock up.

Comment: The first is much better than the second; I wasn't liking that bright blue link too much. But it looks a little strange to be at the *bottom*, even if that is more inconspicuous.

Comment: Option 2 looks good to me too. If it's strange to have the text at the bottom, I don't really mind if it's on top instead.

Answer (score 4):

An excellent-tastic idea!

A blank about me will now show

> (your about me is currently blank)
>
> [click here to edit](http://example.com)

To the user who owns it, instead of a faceless, unforgiving blank grey box.