# Differentiate spoilers from empty block quotes

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, markdown, spoilers

I have to admit, I didn't even know spoilers were supported until today, but really bugs me that spoilers just look like empty block quotes before you mouse over them.

> Is this a spoiler or just a long empty block quote? I can't tell right away, so it would be really nice if there was some indication of which one it was so I didn't have to push my mouse all the way over to it. What can I say, I'm incredibly lazy.

vs.

> 

I suppose the author should include something that says 'Spoilers below:', but it would be nice if there was some other indication of what it was.

Comment: I've thought this before too, +1 for bringing it up for me :P

Comment: +1 these should stand out more readily than just have no text until mouse-over.

Comment: Or, killing two birds with one stone: [render it like the mobile sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104008/could-we-please-have-a-level-two-arrow-of-hiding/104016#104016).

Comment: How do you make a long empty block quote?

Comment: @Bill [Very carefully](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/104089#104089).

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for that.  Now I wonder if you've just created the first one.  I honestly can't see how this is a huge problem for anyone.

Comment: @Bill, the user profiles show a grey block that most people know to simply ignore if empty. So, not knowing about spoilers, I guess one might ignore grey spoiler blocks too. (In fact, I think it's even less obvious if there's only one or two lines. Might just look like some fancy separator, to some.)

Comment: Ah, perfect example of [the differences for spoiler vs. quote on the mobile site](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AZv33.png).

Comment: Even the empty gray block on the user profile [got an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100767/should-there-be-a-link-to-fill-in-user-info-in-the-about-me-box)!

Answer (score 7):

Why would you ever have empty blockquotes?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_%26_Dale#.22Dr._Kronkheit_and_His_Only_Living_Patient.22

> SMITH: Doctor, it hurts when I do this.
>   DALE: Don't do that.

Comment: True, but I feel the point was: somehow indicate they are spoilers. (Like [also noted in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396) underneath the first announcement.)

Comment: You might not have empty block quotes, but that doesn't mean everyone using the site *knows* that there is [generally] no such thing as empty block quotes. If I don't happen to move my mouse in the right spot (and I usually don't move it over stuff I'm trying to read...) then I'd never know that there's hidden text under there. I can't see what's wrong with providing some kind of visual indication, like "(Hover here to reveal text)". (Of course, that said, I've never used spoiler text and I've never actually seen a case where it is required.)

Comment: Someone might call a spoiler a [faceless, unforgiving blank grey box](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100767/should-there-be-a-link-to-fill-in-user-info-in-the-about-me-box/104678#104678)! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I've made a userscript to add `hover to show spoiler` to all spoilers:

```
$('.spoiler').prepend("<div id='isSpoiler' style='color:red; font-size:smaller; float:right;'>hover to show spoiler<div>");
$('.spoiler').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('#isSpoiler').hide(500);
}, function () {
    $(this).find('#isSpoiler').show(500);
});
```

I've added it to my [Optional Features userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I wouldn't mind if spoilers were even harder to spot than it is now. I think

it would be great

> <sub>if small innocent-looking piece of screen could suddenly "explode"</sub>

to show the reader

> a terrific picture like
>  [image: hand-drawn in mspaint image of a narwhal]
>  that has been hidden before hovering