# Use spoilers from mobile theme on regular sites too

Tags: feature-request, rendering, spoilers

On mobile, spoilers show a single small box with the text "Click to show spoiler". Why not use that on the regular sites too?

Advantages:

1. It [works on an iPad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129343/how-do-i-view-spoilers-on-an-ipad) and [any other device](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108090/cant-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen-outside-of-mobile-site).
2. It supports images, which the regular sites [do not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110566/does-the-spoiler-markdown-work-on-images):

   [image: Just 'Click to show spoiler' on mobile theme]
   [image: Expanded spoiler with image] [image: Images not supported in spoiler on regular site.]
3. It doesn't create huge gray blocks for multi-line spoilers.
4. It's [clear to *any* visitor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104085/differentiate-spoilers-from-empty-block-quotes) that's actually something one can click.
5. No accidental revealing when moving the mouse?
6. Consistent layout and behavior for both mobile and the regular sites.

Some disadvantages:

1. One needs to click.
2. Though clicking one spoiler will close the one that was expanded before, one cannot close *all* spoilers on a page (except by reloading the page), or shortly "peek" into a spoiler.
3. Content is repositioned on opening a spoiler. If a large multi-line spoiler is open somewhere above another smaller spoiler, then the smaller spoiler might even scroll out of view when clicking that? Any JavaScript magic to the rescue there?
4. Things are only hidden *after* the page has loaded, which may show the content for a split second. But I'm sure that can be solved.

Not sure:

1. Accessibility: how does a screen reader handle the regular spoilers? And would the mobile theme work better or worse, if at all?
2. SEO: would indexing be any different? (Do we even *expect* search engines to index and possibly show spoiler text?)
3. Review? Does the need for clicking raise the barrier to quickly identify vandalism? And what about peer reviews of suggested edits?

If implemented, it might also be nice if the "Click to show spoiler" text [were a bit more generic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104008/could-we-please-have-a-clickable-arrow-to-expand-hidden-content), like "Click to show hidden text".

Comment: And advantage 7: no more [faceless, unforgiving blank grey box](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100767/should-there-be-a-link-to-fill-in-user-info-in-the-about-me-box/104678#104678) ;-)